# Copying Only files in a directory

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a directory in which there are many different types of files and there are some further directories in the root directory. I just want to copy the files in the root directory and do not want to copy any further directories in the root directory.

I want to do this on command line on Windows.

Comment: I disagree. I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:> copy \*.* [destination folder]
```

This will copy files from the root directory of the current drive (in this example, c:), to a destination folder (which you must substitute for "[destination folder]").

Answer (score 0):

Go into your root folder and try the following:

```
copy *.* C:\WhateverFolder
```

That should only copy the root files not folders into another folder.

You will have to create the other folder first:

```
MD WhateverFolderName
```

If you only wanted to copy files of one type you can change the * . * to say *.exe